# Как сделать "наезд" контента на footer?

Tags: css

Здраствуйте, как можно сделать наезд блока с прайсом на футер как на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой css код для блока с прайсом

```
#pricing{
/* width: 989px; */
margin: 100px auto;
font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica;
position: absolute;
```

}
вот для футера

```
  .footer_content {
padding: 150px 0;
display: flex;
```

}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что именно сейчас работает не так?

Comment: @Grundy добавил скрин

Comment: просто добавь минимальную высоту контейнеру в котором цены лежат, так чтобы ее хватало для первых двух блоков